# Java Rest, how to set and show custom error message

Tags: java, javascript, jersey

When the login fails due to blocked account I want to show a custom message that's set in the backend. But I cant access it in the response body, noot sure even if its set correctly.

```
@POST
@Path(/login)
public Token logon() {
    ...

    String errorMsg = "This account is blocked please contact to Admin"
    throw new NotAuthorizedException(errorMsg);
}
```

And on javascript side when I get the error message I want to do:

```
if (rejection.status === 401) {
    //rejection can be because of blocked account or invalid password,
    //they will both return 401, but need to have different messages 

    $scope.message ="Show the error msg that I get from backend" ;
}
```

Here the returned rejection object consists of config, data, status and headers objects.

But I cant see the msg that I set in the backend anywhere.

Comment: Not sure about this, but receiving or not the error message can depend on the container itself and the way the response is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a response when creating the NotAuthorizedException instead of just a message:

```
@POST
@Path(/login)
public Token logon() {
  ...

  String errorMsg = "This account is blocked please contact to Admin"
  throw new NotAuthorizedException(Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).entity(errorMsg).build())
}
```

This should return your error message in the response body